# How to rotate a pixmap (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

In my game I have a world with randomly generated islands.
My islands are based on the pixel information of the [LibGDX Pixmap class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html).

Now I need to rotate the islands. For this I need to rotate the Pixmaps. Not for drawing, but for reading the pixel data of the rotated Pixmap afterwards.

My problem is, that I don't know how to rotate the Pixmap, so I can read the pixel data of the rotated Pixmap.

Drawing a rotated Pixmap works well, but I need the rotated data persisted, so I can read it.

My code I started with, which doesn't work:

```
public Pixmap rotatePixmap(Pixmap pixmap, int angle){
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(pixmap));
    sprite.setRotation(angle);
    return sprite.getTexture().getTextureData().consumePixmap();
}
```

How can I rotate the Pixmap, so the pixels are altered to the desired rotation?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use for drawing a rotated Pixmap?

Comment: As I wrote. I dont need the pixmap beeing displayed. Imagine I would like to save the rotated Pixmap back to a file. I need the bits of the rotated bitmap to create islands in my own syste,. So what I need is a Pixmap that is really rotated. Drawing a rotated Pixmap works well, but this is not what I need. I hope I explained it well :-)

Comment: Right, I get that you want to generate rotated Pixmap data. What I'm asking is to see how you were drawing it rotated - the reason is, there might be a relatively simple way to use your some of your rotated drawing code to generate a new Pixmap that is also rotated.

Comment: In my code you see that I am creating a Sprite and then setRotation. drawing the spring shows the Sprite (underlying Pixmap) rotated. I still don't don't understand how this can help ?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for clarifying. I was hoping it would lead me to something in the API that directly manipulated/rotated data in a buffer that could then be used to initialize a new Pixmap. If there's such a thing in LibGDX, I didn't find it. I did find something else that might work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As taken from [this post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309848/950488), you can manually build a new Pixmap by sampling from rotated position in the original Pixmap data:

```
public static Pixmap rotatePixmap (Pixmap src, float angle){
    final int width = src.getWidth();
    final int height = src.getHeight();
    Pixmap rotated = new Pixmap(width, height, src.getFormat());

    final double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
    final double cos = Math.cos(radians);
    final double sin = Math.sin(radians);    

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            final int centerX = width/2;
            final int centerY = height / 2;
            final int m = x - centerX;
            final int n = y - centerY;
            final int j = ((int) (m * cos + n * sin)) + centerX;
            final int k = ((int) (n * cos - m * sin)) + centerY;
            if (j >= 0 && j < width && k >= 0 && k < height){
                rotated.drawPixel(x, y, src.getPixel(j, k));
            }
        }
    }
    return rotated;    
}
```

Note: this solution returns a Pixmap with the same dimensions as the target. If you have a rectangular rather than a square Pixmap, this might not be quite what you want. Also, depending on your data, it's possible that some of the image will get clipped. If that's a problem, you'll need to do a little bit of math to adjust the size of the destination Pixmap to make it big enough to accommodate the result.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`Sprite.setRotation`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L334-L338) is realized when calling [`Sprite.getVertices`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L411-L477) or [`Sprite.set`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java#L106-L127). These functions do not transform the underlying texture.

One option is to write your own code to preform the rotation. [This website](http://datagenetics.com/blog/august32013/index.html) is an excellent resource for learning how to do so and what the pitfalls (and solutions) are.